# How to combine summary statistics from 100s of *csv files into one *csv with pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have several hundreds *csv files, which when imported into a pandas data frame look as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename1.csv")

df
    column1  column2   column3    column4
0        10       A          1        ID1
1        15       A          1        ID1
2        19       B          1        ID1
3      5071       B          0        ID1
4      5891       B          0        ID1
5      3210       B          0        ID1
6        12       B          2        ID1
7        13       C          2        ID1
8        20       C          0        ID1
9         5       C          3        ID1
10        9       C          3        ID1
```

Each *csv file has a unique ID for `column4` (whereby each row has the same element).

I would like to create a new csv file, whereby each filename is a row, keeping the ID/value from `column4` and the `max` values of `column1` and `column3`. What is the best pandas way to do this?

ID1   5891    3 
....

My idea would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("*.csv")   # within the correct subdirectory

newdf1 = pd.DataFrame()
for file in newdf1:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df["ID"] = df.column4.unique()
    df["max_column1"] = df.column2.max()
    df["max_column3"] = df.column3.max()
    newdf1 = newdf1.append(df, ignore_index=True)

newdf1.to_csv("totalfile.csv")
```

However, (1) I don't know if this is efficient and (2) I don't know if the dimensions of the final csv is correct. ALSO, how would one deal with a *csv that was missing a `column1` or `column3`? That is, it should "pass" these values.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can loop by files, get first value by `iat` and `max` and append to `list`.

Then use `DataFrame` constructor and write to file.

```
files = glob.glob("*.csv")   # within the correct subdirectory

L = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    u = df.column4.iat[0]
    m1 = df.column1.max()
    m2 = df.column3.max()
    L.append({'ID':u,'max_column1':m1,'max_column3':m2})

newdf1 = pd.DataFrame(L)
newdf1.to_csv("totalfile.csv")
```

EDIT:

```
L = []
for file in files:
    print (file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #print (df)

    m1, m2 = np.nan, np.nan
    if df.columns.str.contains('column1').any():
        m1 = df.column1.max()
    if df.columns.str.contains('column3').any():
        m2 = df.column3.max()
    u = df.column4.iat[0]

    L.append({'ID':u,'max_column1':m1,'max_column3':m2})

newdf1 = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Comment: How would this deal with NA values, i.e. if a column doesn't exist for a certain csv file?

Comment: Hmm, so if column3 is missing , then `max_column3` is NaN?

Comment: Yep, some *csv files do not have a colum1 or column3. Everyone has an ID column 4 though.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated appending to a pandas `DataFrame` is highly inefficient as it copies the DataFrame.
Instead you could write the max values found to the resultant file directly.

```
files = glob.glob("*.csv") 
with open("totalfile.csv", "w") as fout:
    for f in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        result = df.loc[:, ['column4', 'column2', 'column3']].max()\
            .fillna('pass').to_dict()
        fout.write("{column4},{column2},{column3}\n".format(**result))
```

`df.loc[:, ['column4', 'column2', 'column3']]` would return `NaN` filled columns for missing columns. This would raise exception only when all three columns are missing.

`fill_na('pass')` will substitute missing values.

Comment: This for loop doesn't run for me. There's also an error at `fout:`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Sorry for the typo, fixed it now.